# ASN.1 Standardized Identifiers

Tags: asn.1, objectid

ASN.1 OBJECT IDENTIFIERs allow the user to reference a known list of "Standardized Identifiers", without explicitly mentioning the arc number.  For example:

```
oid OBJECT IDENTIFIER = { joint-iso-itu-t asn1(1) base-encoding(1) }
```

Note how `joint-iso-itu-t` has no corresponding number.  This is because it is a known identifier that the ASN.1 compiler is expected to understand.

Is there a list somewhere of all "Standard" identifiers?  A simple Google search for ASN.1 Standard Identifiers doesn't turn up anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

They are specified in ITU-T Rec. X.660 (see http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=x.660).  Search for "NameForm".

Answer (score 0):

**joint-iso-itu-t** is one of the three root nodes of the OID namespace.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier for details.